# Why is Ansible asking me to install the sshpass program when I've specified an ssh connection and key?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I've got this in my inventory:

```
ansible_user=<user>
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=<location of key>
```

and I can ssh in with that user and key.

However, when I run the playbook I get:

```
{"msg": "to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program"}
```

FWIW,

```
Host OS: VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ansible 2.9.9
```

Any suggestions how I can get Ansible to use the ssh key?

UPDATE

Here's what I get with `-vvvvv`:

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.9
  config file = /path/to/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/user/.local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
Using /path/to/ansible.cfg as config file
Reading vault password file: /path/to/ansible-vault.txt
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /path/to/inventory/inventory.win.aws as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /path/to/inventory/inventory.win.aws as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /path/to/inventory/inventory.win.aws as it did not pass its verify_file() method
yaml declined parsing /path/to/inventory/inventory.win.aws as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /path/to/inventory/inventory.win.aws inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py

PLAYBOOK: playbook.yml ******************************************************************************
Positional arguments: playbook.yml
verbosity: 5
connection: smart
timeout: 10
become_method: sudo
inventory: ('/path/to/inventory',)
vault_password_files: ('/path/to/ansible-vault.txt',)
forks: 5
1 plays in playbook.yml

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************
task path: /path/to/playbook.yml:2
<ip.address> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: some_user
fatal: [ip.address]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************
ip.address               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Run `ansible` with the `-vvv` flag, which will show you the exact `ssh` command line it's using. Try running that yourself. That may highlight issues with your ssh configuration that are leading to this behavior. NB: it is almost never necessary to explicitly set `ansible_connection=ssh`, because that's generally the default.

Comment: @larsks it does not show an ssh command.

Comment: What happens if you don't specify it at all in your config? (I honestly thought paramiko was the default connection, be rereading it showed it uses the `smart` mode per default)

Answer (score 1):

This command should produce YAML from your inventory: `ansible-inventory --list -y -i /path/to/inventory/inventory.win.aws` . You can use that output to assert your assumptions.

To validate your connection:

1. Validate if you actually copied your public key! `ssh-copy-id some_user@ip.address`.
2. Then start the SSH agent: `eval $(ssh-agent)`
3. Add the key `ssh-add ~/.ssh/<privkeyfile>`
4. Try a plain ssh `ssh some_user@ip.address` should login without prompt...
5. Try an ansible ping `ansible all -i inventory -m ping -vvvv`

Comment: In my case (similar behaviour to OP), ansible does not appear to be attempting an ssh command, or if it is, it's ignoring ~/.ssh/config  
I have verified that I can ssh to the remote server with user name specified in the playbook without password. When I play the playbook, there is no record in the remote servers sshd logs (ie: no ssh attempt was made).

Comment: `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`